# Wordpress - Adding ajax is preventing the embedding of videos?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, youtube, embed, vimeo

I've just managed to add ajax saving to a theme i'm developing and my theme options are being saved and retrieved correctly.  However, one of my options is video embed text and since I added the aja functionality, the videos will not display.  All I'm getting when I echo the value from my $options array is:

You don't have permission to access /"http://www.youtube.com/embed/u0fk6syQ7iY/" on this server.

The same thing happens with both Youtube and Vimeo videos.
If I paste the embed code directly into my front-end html it works fine but when being retrieved from my theme options I get nothing.

The tutorial I used is this one:
http://return-true.com/2010/01/using-ajax-in-your-wordpress-theme-admin/comment-page-2/#comments

Any idea what the problem is here? Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort out the problem.  Somehow, the new process I implemented was adding backslashes so I had to add stripslashes() to my values before I saved and called them.